# Datepicker datetime format is not working while running the application in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I  am calling the datetime picker to enter the date in dd/mm/yyyy format. I am using the following css and js file in layout file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />      
<style rel="stylesheet"
       href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" />
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@*<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>*@
```

my view file is given below

```js
<script>
        $("#TaxDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy" });
        $("#MOTDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy" });
        $("#InsuredDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy" });
        $("#RegDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy" });
</script
```

```html
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label asp-for="Vehicles.MOTDate" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">MOT Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="MOTDate"
                           asp-for="Vehicles.MOTDate" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Vehicles.MOTDate" class="text-danger">@ViewBag.moterror</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label asp-for="Vehicles.TaxDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Tax Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="TaxDate"
                           asp-for="Vehicles.TaxDate" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Vehicles.TaxDate" class="text-danger">@ViewBag.taxerror</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But  when I run the published site in azure , the date time 'dd/mm/yyyy' format is not working. it is still working as 'mm/dd/yyyy' .
If am going to run in application in localserver it will work . When I run azure it is not working please help  to fix

Comment: I fixed this problem by adding CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture in startup.cs. nowit is working fine .

Comment: I summarized the solution of this case in the answer and updated the answer. Thank you very much for providing the final answer, hope this answer can help more developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This problem was finally solved by modifying `CultureInfo`. The sample code is as follows.

Setting the following in `StartUp.Configure`

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

**PRIVIOUS**

Usually we solve this problem, first ensure that there is no problem with the published file, you can use other methods such as FTP to publish, local testing and deployment to Azure testing.

Comment: I published the same application through  iis hosting , and after when running through published site in IIS ,  it  is working fine .

Comment: When I go through google search many people  have reported the same issue before. I dont know how to fix in azure. It is working fine in localhost publish

Comment: Can you give me a demo just some test data, so I can test it.

Comment: how can I see the published file in Azure. I am using free account in Azure . Also I am not the one having good experience with azure hosting . Is it possible to see the released file in azure?

Comment: Jason, how can I give the demo here? please can you advise me  how to attached the screen layout here as demo

Comment: @systemthreep You can upload the demo without any confidential information to github.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Please can you check this link in github. ppp3pol/VehicleManagement. This is the sample application. After publishing the file in Azure all is being taken as in the format 'mm/dd/yyyy' . The date format should be taken as 'dd/mm/yyyy. But it is not .How can I make it the input text format for the date 'dd/mm/yyyy' Please help. I have already share the code in Github.ppp3pol/VehicleManagement

Comment: Jason please use this link  ppp3pol/Vehicle. please the link given before I given is wrong. correct link ppp3pol/Vehicle. Please can you check the application

Comment: I fixed this problem by adding CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture in startup.cs. Now it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: @systemthreep I summarized the solution of this case in the answer and updated the answer. Thank you very much for providing the final answer, hope this answer can help more developers.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking to do this in ASP.NET Framework (4.x), open up your Global.asax.cs file and add the following to Application_Start (change Culture based on your location):

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CultureInfo customCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = customCulture;
   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = customCulture;
}
```

You may need to include a reference to System.Globalization.